# How to get the list of empty and non-empty ADLS folders using adf pipelines

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am taking the container names from getmetadata activity and on field list passing the child items. So that i got all container names. Then i again used getmetadata activity inside the foreach activity and on field list passing the child items.

Then I used if condition @empty(activity('Get Metadata2').output.childItems) and on True i used append activity and passed @item().name and on False also I used Append activity and passed @item().name.

but on input of append activity i am getting the empty and non empty folder names.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfjyr.png)

but i want the same result on output.

```
{
"name": "pipeline1",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Get Metadata1",
            "type": "GetMetadata",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "DelimitedText6",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "fieldList": [
                    "childItems"
                ],
                "storeSettings": {
                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                },
                "formatSettings": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "ForEach1",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Get Metadata2",
                        "type": "GetMetadata",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "dataset": {
                                "referenceName": "DelimitedText7",
                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "folder": {
                                        "value": "@item().name",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "fieldList": [
                                "childItems"
                            ],
                            "storeSettings": {
                                "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                            },
                            "formatSettings": {
                                "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "If Condition1",
                        "type": "IfCondition",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Get Metadata2",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "expression": {
                                "value": "@empty(activity('Get Metadata2').output.childItems)",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "ifFalseActivities": [
                                {
                                    "name": "false var",
                                    "type": "AppendVariable",
                                    "dependsOn": [],
                                    "userProperties": [],
                                    "typeProperties": {
                                        "variableName": "non empty1",
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "ifTrueActivities": [
                                {
                                    "name": "true var",
                                    "type": "AppendVariable",
                                    "dependsOn": [],
                                    "userProperties": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "a",
                                            "value": "hand"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "typeProperties": {
                                        "variableName": "empty1",
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Copy data1",
            "type": "Copy",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "ForEach1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                    "additionalColumns": [
                        {
                            "name": "empty",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "'@{variables('empty1')}'",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "non empty",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "'@{variables('non empty1')}'",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                    "writeBehavior": "insert",
                    "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
                    "tableOption": "autoCreate",
                    "disableMetricsCollection": false
                },
                "enableStaging": false,
                "translator": {
                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                    "mappings": [
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "name": "empty",
                                "type": "String"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "name": "empty",
                                "type": "String",
                                "physicalType": "nvarchar"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "name": "non empty",
                                "type": "String"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "name": "non empty",
                                "type": "String",
                                "physicalType": "nvarchar"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "typeConversion": true,
                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "DelimitedText8",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "empty1": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "non empty1": {
            "type": "Array"
        }
    },
    "annotations": []
}
}
```

I am expecting an enmpty and non empty folder list on append varriable output

Comment: You want to get the list of empty  and non empty container names or empty folder and non-empty folder names in each container? what is the output of the first Get meta data activity and what it will give list of container names or list of folder names?

Comment: i want a ;ist of empty and non empty container names. first getmetadata activity will return the container names. for eg i have two container names dev and qa . so first getmetadata return these 2 names

Comment: Check the below answer and let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but on input of append activity i am getting the empty and non empty folder names

**Append variable activity will only have the input and its output is always empty**. Every append variable activity input will contain the value that it's going to append to the array in that particular array.

I have used the same JSON to build the below pipeline.

You can see the below input where the `False append` is an **append variable activity in the False activities of if**. It is appending the non-empty container name `data1` to the `Non-empty` array in this iteration as the if expression is false in this case.

[image]

In the case of container is empty, it will execute the **append activity (**`True append`**) in the True activities of if**, and this will have the input like below. It is appending the empty container name `con1` to the `Empty` array variable in this iteration.

[image]

In each iteration it will only show the current iteration input of the activity.

> I am expecting an enmpty and non empty folder list on append varriable output

**At the end of the For-loop**, all respective values will be appended to the array variables `Empty` and `Non-empty`.

If you want to check the output, create another two array variables and assign these to them using set variable activities like below (Here self-referencing variables is not supported in ADF that's why use dummy array variables to check the output).

[image]

Do the same for `Empty` array as well.

**Output of Empty array:**

[image]

**Output of Non-empty array:**

[image]

This is only for checking the output. You can use the original arrays after the for-loop as per your requirement. Check the **Note** in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-append-variable-activity#create-an-append-variable-activity-with-ui) to know more.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. After that with the help of dummy csv file and proper mapping when i tried to load the empty and not empty varriable on sql database table through copy activity  i am getting empty values on both columns(empty and non empty) of table.  I check the input of copy activity i had the empty and non empty file but on output data written was 0

Comment: As your primary ask was resolved which is related to append variable activity, it's better to raise a new question on your new ask with all necessary information like copy activity source sink mapping images, so that I can try to reproduce the entire issue from my end.

Answer (score 0):

- Create 2 variables of array type say var1 for holding empty folders names and another one var2 for non-empty folders names.
- Now, drag 'Get metadata' activity to list down all the folder names
- Use Foreach activity to iterate through all the folders one by one
- Inside Foreach, use another Get metadata activity to get all the sub-folder names or file names present in each of the folders.
- Use 'If activity' , put the condition to check if getmetadata2 activity output is empty or not . For expression use `@empty(activity('Get metadata2').output.childItems)`
- Inside True block, use append variable , select var1 and give expression as `@item().name` and do the same with false block- Add append variable , select var2 and give expression as `@item().name`

Comment: Thanks Annu. After that with the help of dummy csv file and proper mapping when i tried to load the empty and not empty varriable on sql database table through copy activity  i am getting empty values on both columns(empty and non empty) of table.

Comment: you can try using script activity and query insert into table statement with values coming from @{variable('var1')} and @{variable('var2')}